# jquery popup dialog onload instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried many things, but my code (which I downloaded) is different from others, because I cant find any kind of thing document.onload = function which I found and added onload after "document" not worked at all. my js code is:

```
/*
 * jQuery Reveal Plugin 1.0
 * www.ZURB.com
 * Copyright 2010, ZURB
 * Free to use under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/


(function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

    $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
        $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
    });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {


        var defaults = {  
            animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        }; 

        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
            var modal = $(this),
                topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
                topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
                locked = false,
                modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
            if(modalBG.length == 0) {
                modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
            }           

/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
            //Entrance Animations
            modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
              modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
                $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
                if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    }
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                        modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                            "opacity" : 1
                        }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                    } 
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                        unlockModal()               
                    }
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:open');
            });     

            //Closing Animation
            modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
              if(!locked) {
                    lockModal();
                    if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "fade") {
                        modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                            modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                            unlockModal();
                        });                 
                    }   
                    if(options.animation == "none") {
                        modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                    }       
                }
                modal.unbind('reveal:close');
            });     

/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
            //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

            //Close Modal Listeners
            var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });

            if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
                modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
                modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                  modal.trigger('reveal:close')
                });
            }
            $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
            });


/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
            function unlockModal() { 
                locked = false;
            }
            function lockModal() {
                locked = true;
            }   

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

and HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- 
 * Markup for jQuery Reveal Plugin 1.0
 * www.ZURB.com/playground
 * Copyright 2010, ZURB
 * Free to use under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Reveal Demo</title>

        <!-- Attach our CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">   

        <!-- Attach necessary scripts -->
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.reveal.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica-Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; }
            .big-link { display:block; margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color: #06f; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">
            Fade and Pop
        </a>    

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">
            Fade
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="none">
            None
        </a>

        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
            <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If needed I have 2nd javascript code, please dont rate down (I've been blocked for long time). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Modal box is opening??? by clicking where???

Comment: Can you pls explain. More clearly what u want. Do you want your modal dialog box to open when document is loaded ?

Comment: no I want to open dialog automaticly after page loaded :) thank you guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `data-reveal-id` to trigger the plugin with a click. You can also trigger it programmatically. If you want to trigger on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // trigger reveal manually.
  $('#myModal').reveal({
     animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
     animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
     closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
     dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
  });
});
```

For more info read the [documentation](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin).

Comment: **`+1`** Nice solution, the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgtsac94/) for your code ;)

Comment: sorry, but where can I add this code? :) Thank you and sorry for disturb.

Comment: @user3552778 in your html page `<script>/*here*/</script>` after the jquery script. Also you can put it in another file and reference it `<script src="myfile.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the `click` event for your desired link, for example the first link. Add this block code before `</head>`:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-reveal-id]').eq(0).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gw983oq5/).